# Fill the body of request in Postman

Tags: go, postman

The body of request are decoded into my own go struct.

```
// The go struct.
type NewUser struct {
    User            string   `json:"user" validate:"required"`
    Password        string   `json:"password" validate:"required"`
    PasswordConfirm string   `json:"password_confirm" validate:"eqfield=Password"`
}

---

// the web request with body will be decoded into this struct.
var nu NewUser
if err := web.Decode(r, &nu); err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "")
}
```

How should I pass this body into postman.

[image]

Comment: as `raw` with json body.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not eligible for StackOverflow rules.

it's elementary lack of desktop user experience.

[image: screen]